# How to manage initial data in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, flyway

I have a project with a postgresql database. I'm handling migrations with Flyway. Now I have some initial data, that I want to add to the database when the application starts. It's a data that should always be there in the beginning. How could I handle this data initialization properly?

I've been thinking about using Flyways [repeatable migrations](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/migration/repeatable). It is run always if the hash of the sql file changes. The problem is, that then I would need to construct it with sql insert statements. The problem there is, that what if the object already exists? Ideally, I would want that I could specify the data in the sql, and then the migration either inserts it to the table if it doesn't exist. But it should look for each field, not just by primary key. Because if I want to change something in one row, then I would want that to update to the database. Of course I could always drop the whole contents of the table, and then run the migration, but isn't that little cumbersome in the long run? Like always after little edit, I need to drop table and run the migration... I just wonder if there is some better way to handle the initial data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the primary key value with `INSERT` or `COPY` by including the column like any other. With the former, you could add an [`ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE` clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) to make any possible changes. If you're using 9.4 or below, `ON CONFLICT` isn't available so you're stuck with `DELETE` and a plain `INSERT` or `COPY`, although knowing the primary keys means you don't have to delete the entire table.

Comment: Does the ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE clause really work with COPY command too? I see no examples of that online. Only with INSERT

Comment: I could have been clearer there -- it's only usable with `INSERT`.